# Are JSP scriptlets an antipattern?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, scriptlet

I hope you understand the question. What do you think? If I post some code here with scriptlet I'm convinced that you're going to tell me not to use scriptlet whatsoever. Right?

Comment: `Don't use scriplet whatsoever`

Comment: Right! Anti-pattern comes into play in JSP when developer fail to maintain the separation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yes, it should be avoided for a couple of reasons.
At first I really don't appreciate salad in my code :)
JSP is intended for marking up the things, not for logic in the representation layer.
Its just not readable.

At second, when I've started to learn JSP I was told that those who developed JSP thought that in ideal world those who really create jsp pages shouldn't be java programmers.
If you need something that should be done by logic in JSP (conditions/loops and so forth) java programmer will better create tags/ tag files in newer jsp versions.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've inherited a legacy project that uses scriplets for a lot of logic. We're even putting in more scriplets knowing that it's not recommmended.

Answer (score 1):

No , but understanding will be tough and there is no performance related problem

Check this article for more information: [Scriptless JSP Pages: The Front Man](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/Journal200603.jsp#a5)

Answer (score 1):

No logic in JSP. Just plain working with beans. :) So IMO scriplets wouldn't be a good solution. UI must be UI, but not something very heavy.