# Prevent tomcat to log specific Exception

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, logging, stack-trace

Let's say I have the following jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<html>
   <head>
      <title><c:catch> Tag Example</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <c:catch var ="catchException">
         <% int x = 5/0;%>
      </c:catch>

      <c:if test = "${catchException != null}">
         <p>The exception is : ${catchException} <br />
         There is an exception: ${catchException.message}</p>
      </c:if>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I prevent tomcat to log it in tomcat.out with the full stack trace? Starting with

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
```

.......

Basically what i want is to suppress tomcat from logging a specific run time exception that and just log the message not the full stack trace.

Comment: Solution: Don't write Java code in JSPs. See: [Are JSP scriptlets an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13081818/5221149)

Comment: this is not java code, is jstl. The point was not related to the java exception but rather how to deal with tomcat not to log a runtime exception

Comment: `<% int x = 5/0;%>` is a scriptlet, and `int x = 5/0;` is **Java code**. --- When you stop writing Java code in the JSP, you also stop needing to catch and suppress the exception in JSP. So the solution to not having Tomcat log the exception, is to ... not write Java code in JSPs. --- I guess your alternative, if you insist on writing Java code in the JSP, would be to do the `try-catch` inside the scriptlet too.